# Typescript children on Nodes

Tags: javascript, parsing, typescript, dom

In Javascript this Code works like a acharm, in Typescript I get the following Error:

> Property 'children' does not exist on type 'Node'.

This is my code

```
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var res = parser.parseFromString(xmldata, "text/xml")
    var branches = res.getElementsByTagName("Branch")
    branches[i].childNodes[7].children
```

Comment: instead of `childNodes` you could try `children` which should return instances of `Element` instead of `Node`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error occurs because there is no field `children` in the definition file for the `Node` interface. The typescript compiler will prompt an error if the property you're trying to access on an object does not exist. You can see the entire definition file [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts).

What happens is that the selected child node is an instanceof `Element`. The `childNodes` method returns an implementation of the interface `NodeList` which is an iterator for objects of the type Node. When you look at the definition for the Element interface, you can see that it inherits `Node`, `ChildNode` and `ParentNode` interfaces. The ParentNode interface is the one that contains the readonly attribute `children`. You can apply casts to objects in Typescript to the proper element type.

```
let el = <Element> branches[i].childNodes[7];
el.children;
// or without declaring a new variable
(<Element> branches[0].childNodes[0]).children;
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work with `typescript`

```
const parentEl = document.getElementById('parentId')
if (!parentEl) {
  return
}

const childElements = Object.values(parentEl.childNodes) as HTMLElement[]
for (const childEl of childElements) {
  console.log(childEl.offsetLeft)
}
```